# Use multiple constructors in Java AnnotationLibrary for RobotFramework test

Tags: java, robotframework

In my Test I would like to create an instance of my Library class with given parameter. I have a following code:

```java
@RobotKeywords
public class MyKeywords {

    private String defaultText;

    public MyKeywords() {
        this("Default greeting");
    }

    public MyKeywords(String defaultText) {
        this.defaultText = defaultText;
    }

    @RobotKeyword
    public void printSomeStuff() {
        System.out.println(this.defaultText);
    }

}
```

And test:

```
*** Settings ***
Library  cz.robot.MyRobotLibrary  Instance greeting  WITH NAME  my_instance

*** Test Cases ***
Custom keyword test
    my_instance.Print Some Stuff
```

When running test I am getting following:

> [ ERROR ] Error in file 'C:\Users\michal.golis\work\robotpoc\src\test\robotframework\acceptance\custom.robot': Test Library 'cz.robot.MyRobotLibrary' expected 0 arguments, got 1.

Any idea how to make it work? Code works fine when I remove "Instance greeting" from test. But offcourse I won't be having desired capability to initialize defaultText in a test file. I don't want to make a special keyword for this kind of functionality.

Answer (score 0):

When I looked at the javalibcore [documentation](http://robotframework-javalibcore%20-%20AnnotationLibrary.wiki), it does not mention anything about multiple constructors , just talks about default constructor. However, what one can do is [overload](https://github.com/robotframework/JavalibCore/wiki/AnnotationLibrary) Robotkeyword methods.